# php preg_replace content type

Tags: php, preg-replace

How can I check if the content of `preg_replace` function is numeric/alphanumeric or not?

e.g.

if numeric :

```
$link= preg_replace("'\< (.*)\>'Ui","< <a href=\"x.php?id=\\1\">\\1</a>>",$link);
```

else

```
$link= preg_replace("'\< (.*)\>'Ui","< <a href=\"x.php?word=\\1\">\\1</a>>",$link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [ctype_alnum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) function

> ```
> bool ctype_alnum ( string $text )
> ```
>
> Checks if all of the characters in the
>   provided string, text, are
>   alphanumeric. In the standard C locale
>   letters are just [A-Za-z].

Comment: if there are more words in the text, not just $link?
eg, i want to change all values in < > tags. how can i check?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your question.